# Are there any downsides for the same API to perform two slightly different functions?

Tags: api-design

Take for example the following two `GET` requests with slightly different arguments:

```
../user/login_at
```

which returns the last login date of the user, and

```
../user/login_at?start=2015-05-01&end=2015-05-31
```

which returns an array of all login dates of the user within May.

Are there any downsides for this API to perform these two slightly different functions?

Answer (score 8):

I could think of, 
in the first example the user expecting a string or json Object value to return. But in the second example, the user expecting to return an array. 
It may lead the user to create messy `if else` statement.

It would be better if you rename the endpoint to.

`/user/last_login_at`

and

`/user/login_logs`

Answer (score 0):

No. I think they are clear and should be different because they perform different tasks, even if they perform activities for the same entity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a Boolean parameter, so that you retrieve the last login by:

/user/login_at?last

You effectively then have one endpoint that filters by query string, and could use a call like:

/user/login_at?start=2015-05-01&end=2015-05-31&last

...to get the last login time in May.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some inconvenience in parsing the answer, as already noted by [bekicot](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/u/115790) in [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/286538):

The problem is that your result has a different structure for the two cases.
Why does it have that gratuitious difference?
Simply make the first query answer with a single-element-array, and all is fine.

Aside from that, there's no problem at all. It's analogous to function overloading in languages like C++, where different overloads (different number and type of parameters) can return different result-types.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. If you know any prospective users of the API, you could ask them if it would be better to always return an array; with one entry if only the last login of the user is requested; this also means that returning an empty array is a perfectly fine way to tell the client that the user never actually logged in.

The client can then use identical code to process the answer to the point where he/she has an array of objects, typically 1 and sometimes 0 entries in the first case, and any number of entries in the second case.